# Find $\,f(n)\,$ s.t. $\,n\cdot f(n)\cdot f(f(n))\cdot f(f(f(n)))=1\,$ for $\,n\gt1$

Tags: functions

I have to find all functions $\,f:Q\rightarrow Q\;$ such that $\;n\cdot f(n)\cdot f(f(n))\cdot f(f(f(n)))=1\,$ for all $\,n\gt1$.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: $f(n) = \frac 1n$

Comment: I found also: $- \frac 1 n,\;\frac {n-1} {n+1},\;\frac {1+n} {1-n}$.

Comment: Let $f^{(r)}\triangleq \underset{r\text{ times}}{\underbrace{f(f(\ldots f}}(\cdot)))$. Then, 
$$ \frac{n \cdot f(n)\cdot f^{(2)}(n)\cdot f^{(3)}(n)}{f(n) \cdot f^{(2)}(n)\cdot f^{(3)}(n)\cdot f^{(4)}(n)}=1\implies f^{(4)}(n)=n \implies f^{(2)}(f^{(2)}(n)) = n,  $$
Thus, $f^{(2)}(n)$ is is its own inverse if $n,f(n)>1$, i.e., $f^{(2)}(\cdot)$ is an involution.